# Show Progressbar when loading data using EntityFrameWork in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework

I want to show the progress of Data being fetched from Database in a `Progressbar`. Currently i am updating the content of a `Button`. Have no idea how to implement in this code .

```
private async void FetchInvoicesDataFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loading Data ...";
   InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = await  Task.Run(FetchInvoiceDataAsync);
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loaded !";

 }

private async Task<List<Invoice>> FetchInvoiceDataAsync()
 {
   List<Invoice> result;
   using(var context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities() )
    {  
      result  = await context.Invoices.Where(b => b.InvoiceID <= 2000).Include(x => x.Customer).ToListAsync();      
    }
        return  result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to track the "progress" of the query, at least not as a percentage. When fetching a lot of data, you could consider splitting your query in mulitple queries and then show the progress.

Comment: How can i split it . have no idea :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to show the percentage of an EF-Query, as it doesn't notify you about the progress of the DB query (I don't know any DB-System that keeps the client informed about the status of a query)

You could consider splitting your query into pieces like this:

```
 private async void FetchInvoicesDataFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   List<Invoice> results = new List<Invoice>();
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loading Data ...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(0, 500));  
   ProgressBtn.Content = "25% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(501, 1000)); 
   ProgressBtn.Content = "50% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1001, 1500)); 
   ProgressBtn.Content = "75% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1501, 2000));        
   InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = results;
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loaded !";    
 }

 private async Task<List<Invoice>> FetchInvoiceDataAsync(int start, int end)
 {
   List<Invoice> result;
   using(var context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities() )
   {  
     result  = await context.Invoices.Where(b => b.InvoiceID >= start && b.InvoiceID <= end).Include(x => x.Customer).ToListAsync();      
   }

   return  result;
 }
```

Please note that this will have a negative impact on the performance of your application. 
There are thousands of tutorials how to use progressbars both in WinForms and WPF so i won't dive into that topic.

Comment: YEAH Thanks ! it is working but UI hangs every time progress is made ! and i don't know how to resolve that :(

Comment: That was awesome ! but still Ui hangs for a sec when Data is loaded into DataGrid . just before Data is shown into DataGrid !

Comment: You already had this freeze of the UI before using my code, right? Unfortunately you won't be able to get rid of this little freeze. At least i don't know how to. When "InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = results" executes your UI is redrawn. This makes the UI freeze and as I already said I don't think you'll be able to get rid of this.

Comment: I will get rid of this hopefully  ! But really appreciate your help ! thanks brother :)