# Use ProgressBar to monitor the execution progress of SQL query and update progress bar percentage if field_id of sql table increments by 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I totally don't have a clue on how to implement this. I did some effort after searching on StackOverflow but it is clearly something unprecedented to me.

*To write this question in first place I made the assumption that a progress bar cannot be updated based on the progress of an sql query because it is not aware of HOW the sql query progress.*

First, I will describe my concept. I have a MainWindow class on which my application is designed. On this MainWindow class I have a button called "*Run*". This button when clicked it runs a very time consuming sql query with by calling 7 stored procedures. Specifically, the query takes about 4 mins to execute. So my initial thought, was to create a progress bar that will show to the user the progress execution of the query instead of *freezing* the application screen and w8 for 4 mins.

**MainWindow class**

```cs
namespace TestEnvironment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string Args(this string str, params object[] args)
        {
            return String.Format(str, args);
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {   
        private LoginScreen _LoginScreen;
        private CreateProjectScreen _CreateProjectScreen;

        public MainWindow(LoginScreen loginscreen, CreateProjectScreen createprojectscreen)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _LoginScreen = loginscreen; //2nd window
            _CreateProjectScreen = createprojectscreen; //3rd window
        }

    private void RunCalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate {
                    ProgressBarTemplate win_progressbar = new ProgressBarTemplate();
                    win_progressbar.Show();
                }); //Added the Application.Current Dispatcher because of the STA thread error

                //Some extra code after the progress-bar is completed.
                //...//

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

**ProgressBarTemplate window class**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestEnvironment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class ProgressBarTemplate : Window
    {
        private CreateProjectScreen _CreateProjectScreen;
        private LoginScreen _LoginScreen;

        public ProgressBarTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static int RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername)
        {
            bool exists = Directory.Exists(foldername);

            if (!exists)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(foldername);
            }

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    var calculations_query = String.Format(
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_1]; \n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_2]; \n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_3] " + "'{0}', " + "';' " + ";\n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_4] " + "'{0}', " + "';' " + ";\n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_5]; \n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_6] " + "'{0}', " + "';' " + ";\n" +
                    "--EXEC [dbo].[procedure_7]; \n" +
                    "--EXEC [dbo].[procedure_8] " + "'{0}', " + "';' " + ";\n" +
                    "EXEC [dbo].[procedure_9]"
                    , foldername);

                    using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(calculations_query, sqlConnection);

                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 60 * 10;

                    int NumbderOfRecords = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return NumbderOfRecords;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return -100;
            }
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
                worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
           
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            int IsSuccessful = RunCalculationsMethod("Server=localhost;Database=TestProgressBarDB;Integrated Security=SSPI", String.Format("C:\\folder_test\\"));
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is called on the UI thread when the DoWork method completes
            // so it's a good place to hide busy indicators, or put clean up code

            try
            {
                this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("DQ Calculations completed successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProgressBar xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestEnvironment.ProgressBarTemplate"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="ProgressBarTemplate"
        Height="100"
        Width="300"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1">
    <Border Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">
        <Grid Margin="20,10,10,10" Focusable="False">
            <ProgressBar
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignLinearProgressBar }"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="100"
                Name="pbStatus"
                Value="75"
                Height="15"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                Foreground="Green"
                Background="LightGray"
                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                Focusable="False"
                Padding="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignButtonTextBlock}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="13"
                       FontWeight="Medium"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Margin="0,7,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

This is the code I am running at the moment. However, even though my query starts to execute correctly and the Progress Bar is shown, the percentage progress is never changed. It is stuck in 75% (default xaml text added to my progressbar) for 4 mins until it is completed.

[image]

My goal is first to make the progressbar working (meaning to change the percentage value). The second goal is to change the progress of the bar based on a custom statement as stated in question's title.

> Check every 5 secs an SQL log table and update the progress bar by 0.88% only when the field_id of the step is incremented by 1. The 0.88% is the number of steps / 100% = 88 steps / 100. The 88 steps are necessary to complete for the whole query to be successful. So the query starts on step 1 with id 1, after 5 secs I want to check the table and if the step 2 with id 2 is completed then increment the progress bar by 0.88%. Then after 5 secs re-check the sql table and if the step 3 with id 3 is written change the progress bar another 0.88% now in total 1.76%. Do this until 100% percent.

I query the SQL table where field_id is like

```cs
public List<int> GetFieldId(string connectionstring)
{
    List<int> fieldid= new List<int>();

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        var query = "SELECT TOP(1) l.LOG_ID FROM LOG_DETAILS l ORDER BY 1 DESC"

        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query , sqlConnection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    fieldid.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            sqlCommand.Cancel();
        }
    }
    return fieldid;
}
```

Call the method like

```cs
int number_field_id = GetFieldId("Server=localhost;Database=TestProgressBarDB;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

So every 5 seconds execute the method GetFieldId() get the top field_id and if it is incremented by 1 from the previous check (past 5 seconds) progress the bar by 0.88%.

Please consider my effort writing the question as I tried to make it as clear as possible.

[1 possible solution - But not preferred]

Since I know that I will w8 for 4 mins until the query executes I can do something like

```cs
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(60*4 + 10); //+10 secs
    }
}
```

But this is not dynamic since I don't know that every time it will be 4 mins lets say. It's on my local machine that runs 4mins.

Related SO questions searched about:

- [Show Progressbar when loading data using EntityFrameWork in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954554/show-progressbar-when-loading-data-using-entityframework-in-wpf)
- [Progress bar for long running task in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759386/progress-bar-for-long-running-task-in-c-sharp/20760176)

Comment: SQL queries work best when they are short, therefore you wouldn't need a progress bar.  Have you run the query optimiser to check that you aren't missing some indexes?  Also, perhaps SQL is not the best way to store your data for optimum querying

Comment: @Neil don't stuck there because the SQL queries should run for 4mins. This is something that I cannot overpass. My point is how can I attach a progress bar so the user can get notified that the query will end soon. Because imagine when you download a new program and your screen freezes until the program is fully downloaded. Wouldn't you want to have a progress to know how minutes the download will take? Its the same logic here with my progress bar :)

Comment: @JohnG Ok let me reply in order to see if I get your point. So querying a table and taking the field id while the progress bar is executing is non feasible. Because as you say its like I progress the bar on my own. But alternatively, based on my example if this is not feasible is there a way to make the progress bar working? Because for now it is freezed. Also I have created the progress bar code based on this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759386/progress-bar-for-long-running-task-in-c-sharp/20760176.

Comment: I hope your folder names don't contain quotes. See [why parameters are a best practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/). I would show progress to the use based on completion of each proc rather than trying to estimate time.

Comment: @JohnG I added some update on my question

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you please post more about your approach? For example, how am I gonna know when a procedure ends? Is this different than checking an SQL table that rights some checkpoints (like I try to do)? Also, what should I look for in your posted link?

Comment: @NikSp, instead of executing all the procs in one batch, you could execute one-at-titme and update status when each completes.

Comment: @DanGuzman Ty for your reply. Is it feasible do you to provide an answer or at least a link with such an implementation? It would be very helpful to me :)